# Exhausted Virtual Memory Installing SyntaxNet Using Docker Toolbox

Tags: docker, tensorflow, bazel, syntaxnet, docker-toolbox

I exhausted my virtual memory when trying to install [SyntaxNet](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/syntaxnet) from this [Dockerfile](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/syntaxnet/Dockerfile) using the Docker Toolbox. I received this message when compiling the Dockerfile:

```
ERROR: /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/5b21cea144c0077ae150bf0330ff61a0/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/kernels/BUILD:1921:1: C++ compilation of rule '@org_tensorflow//tensorflow/core/kernels:svd_op' failed: gcc failed: error executing command /usr/bin/gcc -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE '-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1' -fstack-protector -Wall -Wl,-z,-relro,-z,now -B/usr/bin -B/usr/bin -Wunused-but-set-parameter -Wno-free-nonheap-object -fno-canonical-system-headers ... (remaining 115 argument(s) skipped): com.google.devtools.build.lib.shell.BadExitStatusException: Process exited with status 1. virtual memory exhausted: Cannot allocate memory ____Building complete. ____Elapsed time: 8548.364s, Critical Path: 8051.91s
```

I have a feeling this could be resolved by changing Bazel's default jobs limit with (for example) `--jobs=1`, however I'm not sure where I would put that in the Dockerfile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possibilities: You could either modify the Dockerfile so that it creates a `~/.bazelrc` that contains the following text:

```
build --jobs=1
```

Note that this works, even though the Dockerfile runs `bazel test` (as opposed to `bazel build`), because `build` flags in the `.bazelrc` also apply to Bazel's `test` command.

The other possibility would be to modify the `RUN` command in the Dockerfile to include the `--jobs=1` parameter, e.g. `RUN [...] && bazel test --jobs=1 --genrule_strategy=standalone [...]`.

Bazel should then spawn not more than a single child process during the build. You can verify this by running "ps axuf" on your host and looking at the process tree of your container. If you modified the `RUN` cmd, you should also see the `--jobs=1` parameter on Bazel's command-line.